# Remove last four characters from a string in C

Tags: c, string

I want to remove the last four characters from a string in C.
Eg: name = "Photo1.jpg", I want to remove tha last four characters (.jpg). Can someone help me out writing a funtion for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want loose the original string, you have to create a new one:

```
char* cut_four (char* s){
    int n;
    int i;
    char* new;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
    // lenght of the new string
    n = i - 4 + 1;
    if (n < 1)
        return NULL;
    new = (char*) malloc (n * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        new[i] = s[i];
    new[i] = '\0';
    return new;
}
```

Comment: Why sizeof(char) always will be 1 if I remember

Comment: Yup 6.5.3.4.3 When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char,
(or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1. When applied to an operand that has array
type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.84) When applied to an operand
that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of bytes in such an object,
including internal and trailing padding.

Comment: But depends on the architecture, processor, etc... I think it's better always use the sizeof because is some kind of standard and too because it's a compile-time operator, it means that it changes nothing in the performance of your program.

Comment: It does not - that is from the C99 standard - it is required that sizeof(char) returns 1

Comment: It depends on the C language. `sizeof(char) == 1`, always. If you want to know the “real” size of a `char`, you can read `CHAR_BIT`, which is 8 on normal systems, and possibly larger on crazy systems. (I don’t think it can be smaller.)

Comment: Right - CHAR_BIT cannot be <8 according to standard

Comment: any reason not to use string library functions like `strlen()`? `strncpy()`?

Comment: Suggest check to insure string is at least 4.

Comment: @chux It looks like it just writes an empty string if the length is less than four. Although I would use `strndup` if it’s available, since it does the same thing as this function.

Comment: @yellowantphil If `i` was 3, `n` would be a _very_ large number, maybe `INT_MAX`, certainly creating problems.

Comment: @yellowantphil `n` may be an `int`, but `void *malloc(size_t size)` takes an unsigned value making negative `n` passed to a very large memory allocation which likely fails and returns `NULL` - then code assumes a non-NULL return, --> further problems.  All-in-all this answer needs to insure the input string not too short, else code like this is a prime hacker exploits.

Answer (score 5):

Since C strings end at the first null character, you can simply put a null character at the `length-4` position to truncate it.

```
size_t len = strlen(string);
if (len >= 4) {
    string[len-4] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* removeLastN(char* str, size_t n ) {
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    str[n <= strLen ? strLen-n : 0] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

The above function will remove the given number of bytes `n` from the end of the string, if the string is long enough that it contains that many bytes. If it contains equal to or fewer than `n` bytes, then the function will remove all bytes in the string, leaving it empty.

Here's a demo showing how to remove exactly 4 bytes from the end of a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* removeLastN(char* str, size_t n );

int main(void) {
    char str[32] = "Photo1.jpg";
    printf("\"%s\"\n", removeLastN(str,4) );
    return 0;
}

char* removeLastN(char* str, size_t n ) {
    size_t strLen = strlen(str);
    str[n <= strLen ? strLen-n : 0] = '\0';
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Will this work for me to remove last four characters?

Comment: Yes it will, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a copy of the original string, without the last four characters, you can use `strndup`. It’s part of POSIX 2008, and may not be available on your system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char fullname[] = "Photo1.jpg";
    char *name;
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(fullname);
    // strndup returns a pointer to an array that it created
    name = strndup(fullname, len >= 4 ? len - 4 : 0);
    printf("%s\n", name);  // prints "Photo1"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember that strings in C are an array of characters, terminated by a `NUL` byte.

You can simply "cut off" the end of the string by replacing the first character to be removed with  `'\0'`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void trim_end(char *str, int n)
{
    n = strlen(str) - n;

    if (n < 0)
        n = 0;

    str[n] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char name[] = "Photo1.jpg";

    printf("Before: name = \"%s\"\n", name);

    trim_end(name, 4);

    printf("After: name = \"%s\"\n", name);

    trim_end(name, 4);

    printf("After: name = \"%s\"\n", name);

    trim_end(name, 4);

    printf("After: name = \"%s\"\n", name);


    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 
Before: name = "Photo1.jpg"
After: name = "Photo1"
After: name = "Ph"
After: name = ""
```

Note that `name` here is a `char []`, and not `char *`.  The former is an array (which lives on the stack of `main` that has been *initialized* to "Photo1.jpg".  The latter is a string *literal* which usually live in read-only memory; attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Comment: So long as it's not a string literal of course

Comment: Can you show that as an example because I started learning c so dont have that kind of knowledge. If you can show me how it can be attained , it will be great.

Comment: Notice @Barmar has a good point about initial length

Comment: won't let me edit the comment - so
coredump on char name[]="A";

Comment: Obviously you need to check the length; this was a proof-of-concept for the fixed input string. Sorry for being the only answer here with a full working example. Wow.

Comment: @yellowantphil Yes, now there are. There were not when I wrote this (before any other answers).